# Как сделать мультиязычный лендинг?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Подскажите, как реализовать мультиязычный лендинг?

Comment: [NPM пакет для мультиязычности](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next)
 и    [How does internationalization work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084675/how-does-internationalization-work-in-javascript)

Можно, конечно, сделать и отдельные сайты -- так проще. Но минус отдельных сайтов в том, что их сложней сопровождать -- легко забыть обновить сайт на другом языке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Реализация на JS + HTML + CSS3

Если решили делать на JS + HTML + CSS3, то сделайте себе несколько лендингов под разные языки и переключайтесь между ними с помощью ссылок или JS.

Например, создаем три версии:

**site.com** - англоязычная версия,

**site.com/ru/** - русскоязычная версия,

**site.com/ch/** - китайская версия

И в шапке добавляйте блок переключения в виде флажков обычными ссылками на подпапки:

```
<a href="/ru/">ru</a>
```

Можно так же сделать select выпадающий список где при смене будет перенаправление на нужную версию.

```html
<select onChange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="/">EN</option>
<option value="/ru/">RU</option>
<option value="/ch/">CH</option>
</select>
```

### Реализация на PHP

Если хотите сделать на php, то можно занести весь текст в переменные (по 3 раза для каждого из языков соответственно), и в дальнейшем передавать актуальный язык через $_GET параметр.

Проверять его значение и выводить нужные языковые переменные.

Думаю в случае лендинга это пустая трата времени. Разумнее сделать с подпапками на HTML + JS + CSS.